# ¿Como instalar y usar PyQt5 en Windows?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pycharm

Buenas, descargue PyQt5 de su pagina oficial y en algunos vídeos veo que trae un archivo "ejecutable" llamado diseñador. Al descargarlo no trae dicho archivo, solo una carpeta llamada así que no se que hacer con ella, entonces ¿como puedo usar PyQt?
La siguiente imagen tiene todo lo que contiene el directorio despues de descomprimirlo, utilizo como IDE PyCharm.
¿Alguien, por favor, me puede ayudar?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El designer forma parte de las librerias QT, si descargas pyqt probablemente no lo estes descargando o tengas que compilarlo.
Para que en windows te instale el designer tienes que instalarlo desde https://www1.qt.io/download-open-source/?hsCtaTracking=f977210e-de67-475f-a32b-65cec207fd03%7Cd62710cd-e1db-46aa-8d4d-2f1c1ffdacea
En el instalador podras descargar la versión que quieras de QT y los programas extras que incluye: designer, creator, studio3d.....
Una vez instalado todo, vas al icono de windows > programas > QT y ahí los tienes.

Comment: Buenas por favor mejora tu respuesta, ve [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que la comunidad te entienda mejor y sea realmente aceptada.

Answer (score 2):

Abre una consola de comando y tipeas `pip3 install PyQt5`, comenzará a trabajar, debes dejarlo así hasta que llegue al 100%. 
Cuando termine esto, se te va a crear automáticamente una carpeta dentro de donde tengas instalado el Python así `\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5`.
Con esto solamente vas poder ejecutar los programas, pero no vas a poder diseñar.
Para descargar el designer, tenes que tipear lo siguiente:
`pip3 install PyQt5-tools`, esto te va a crear otra carpeta `\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5-tools`, y acá dentro se encuentra el designer.exe
Ya lo he probado y funciona.
Suerte.

Answer (score 1):

La forma recomendada para descargar PyQt5 (y la mayoría de paquetes python) es abrir una terminal y escribir `pip install pyqt5` o bien `pip3 install pyqt5`. Ahora bien, tu has descargado el archivo con extensión .zip de la página oficial de PyQt, lo que debes hacer es:

1. Abre una terminal y ubícate en la carpeta que acabas de descomprimir.
2. Escribe `python configure.py`, con esto ejecutarás el archivo de configuración de PyQt5.
3. Ahora debes construir el ejecutable, para ello escribes en la terminal `make`.
4. Por último, queda instalar PyQt5 en tu ordenador, para ello escribes `make install`

Los pasos anteriores dan por sentado que tienes el interprete de Python configurado correctamente en el path de tu sistema.

Fuentes:

- [1] : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html
- [2] : README de la carpeta de instalación de Pyqt5.