# Como instalar PyQt5 en Windows

Tags: python, pyqt5

intente instalar PyQt5 pero me dio el siguiente error[image: error]

¿Alguien sabe como arreglar esto, como puedo instalarlo?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Python usas? Si usas Python >= 3.3 lo más simple para la versión GPL es usar el wheels que se proporciona vía [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt5) : `pip install PyQt5`/`python -m pip install PyQt5` (activando previamente el entorno virtual ).

Comment: Mira aquí : [¿Como instalar y usar PyQt5 en Windows?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67995/como-instalar-y-usar-pyqt5-en-windows) **Posible Duplicado**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `pip install PyQt5` y si necesitas instalar el QtDesigner utiliza `pip install pyqt5-tools`

y el QtDesigner estara en una ruta similar a esta:

```
C:\Users\tu-usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma más fácil de instalar `PyQt` es simplemente usar el instalador, enlace de descarga [aquí](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5). Si instala [Python 3.XX](https://www.python.org/getit/), el instalador agregará todos los extras de `PyQt5`automáticamente a esa instalación de `python`. No necesitará hacer ninguna compilación (ninguno de: `nmake`, `nmake install`, `python configure`).

Todas las opciones de compilación están disponibles si necesita una instalación personalizada (por ejemplo, usando una versión diferente de python, donde no hay un instalador proporcionado).

Si necesita compilar su propia versión de `PyQt5`, los pasos para hacer esto están [aquí](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html) , pero suponga que tiene `python` y un compilador instalado y en su ruta. El instalado y en su ruta ha estado donde usted ha estado corriendo en problemas, parece. Recomiendo usar la versión del instalador, pero primero debe instalar [Python 3.XX](https://www.python.org/getit/).

> Tu pregunta es un posible duplicado de: [¿Como instalar y usar PyQt5 en Windows?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67995/como-instalar-y-usar-pyqt5-en-windows)